# how to list all publicly accessible GCP resources?

Tags: security, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, assets, google-iam

i need to list all of the publicly accessible GCP resources in my organisation for security enhancement, is it possible to do it with gcloud console ? mainly i need to list publicly resources for

1. Storage
2. SQL
3. GKE
4. Firewall rules

if possible, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Google Cloud Security Command Center](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center). It detects and lists Cloud Storage buckets with public access, VMs and Cloud SQL instances with public IP and open firewall rules.